# Dead Lock occur when foreign key exists on table

Tags: sql-server, database, foreign-keys, deadlock

There are two table exist in DB, Audit and AuditField, following is the Create table code:

```
-- Primary key: ID
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Audit](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[TypeName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
) 
GO

-- Primary key: ID
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AuditField](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[AuditID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Field1] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
)

GO
-- Set foreign key on AuditField table 
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AuditField] 
ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_AuditFiled_Audit] FOREIGN KEY([AuditID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Audit] ([ID])
GO
```

Then I prepared some test data:

```
DECLARE @audit TABLE
(
ID int not null,
TypeName varchar(50)
)

DECLARE @auditField TABLE
(
AuditID int not null,
Field1 varchar(50)
)

-- ADD TEST DATA
DECLARE @i int = 1
DECLARE @rowCount int = 500
WHILE @i<=@rowCount
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @audit
VALUES(@i, 'SomeTypeName')

INSERT INTO @auditField
(AuditID,Field1)
VALUES(@i,'SomeThing')

SET @i += 1
END
```

Finally, i run following transaction to insert test data to these two table:

```
begin transaction
INSERT INTO dbo.Audit
SELECT TypeName
FROM @audit
ORDER BY ID

declare @lastIdentity int = @@identity
declare @offSet int = @lastIdentity - @rowCount

INSERT INTO dbo.AuditField
SELECT AuditID+@offSet AS AuditID, Field1
FROM @auditField 
ORDER BY AuditID
commit transaction
```

When this transaction run concurrent, dead lock occur, one process are failed, the other got an error：

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 40 The INSERT statement conflicted
>   with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_AuditFiled_Audit". The conflict
>   occurred in database "MyDB", table "dbo.Audit", column 'ID'.

There is no trigger on Audit and AuditField table.
Sorry for the format of the code, I really need an answer why this dead lock occur, thanks.

One thing should be clear, the data of AuditField table comes from @auditField, As @Bogdan answer I rewrite like this:

```
begin transaction
INSERT INTO dbo.Audit
OUTPUT inserted.ID INTO @temp
SELECT TypeName
FROM @audit

INSERT INTO @idMapping
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS RowNumber, ID
FROM @temp

INSERT INTO dbo.AuditField
SELECT m.ID AS AuditID, Field1
FROM @auditField af
INNER JOIN @idMapping m ON af.AuditID = m.RowNumber

commit transaction
```

Comment: It should be ok now because `INSERT INTO dbo.AuditField ...` will inserted only the `AuditID` values generated by `INSERT INTO dbo.Audit ...` within same transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is and Read - Write deadlock:
[image]

As you can see, every transaction has successfully acquired an [e]X[clusive] lock and it requests a S[hared] lock. The question is why a transaction try to read rows X locked by another transaction.

And the answer is bellow: 
1) Following piece of source code

```
declare @lastIdentity int = @@identity
declare @offSet int = @lastIdentity - @rowCount
```

assumes that `IDENTITY` values generated by every

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Audit
SELECT TypeName
FROM ...
```

statement are continues. This is completely wrong as you can see in the following picture:

[image]

This means that at some point in time, a transaction could successfully get X locks on inserted rows and then 
1) Because inserted rows into Audit aren't continuous and
2) Because of

```
declare @lastIdentity int = @@identity
declare @offSet int = @lastIdentity - @rowCount

INSERT INTO dbo.AuditField
SELECT AuditID+@offSet AS AuditID, Field1 ...
```

this last `INSERT` tries to insert into `dbo.AuditField`, `AuditID` values that belong to another transaction and this requires `FK` validation and, also, means that SQL Server needs to read rows from `dbo.Audit`. For this S[hared] locks are needed.

To be clear: the root cause of this deadlock is not the FK constraint. The real problem is that source code.

Solution: I would rewrite thus:

```
begin transaction
INSERT INTO dbo.Audit
OUTPUT inserted.ID, inserted.TypeName INTO @audit (ID, TypeName)
SELECT TypeName
FROM @audit
-- ORDER BY ID -- Isn't necessary 

... do something (ex. DELETE) with rows from @audit

INSERT INTO dbo.AuditField (AuditID, ...)
SELECT x.ID, ...
FROM @audit x
-- ORDER BY AuditID 

/* or 
    INSERT INTO dbo.AuditField (AuditID, Field1, ....)
    SELECT y.ID, y.ColumnName, ...
    FROM (
        SELECT x.ID, ...
        FROM @audit x
        UNPIVOT( ColumnValue FOR ColumnName IN ([TypeName], ...) )
    ) y
    WHERE y.....
*/
commit transaction -- Isn't necessary
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know why this deadlock occur. There is one more question about your solution, use OUTPUT I can get the ID inserted, is there a sample way to map ID with @auditField.AuditID?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert an invalid foreign key value into dbo.AuditField:

```
SELECT AuditID+@offSet AS AuditID, Field1
```

Why the @offset?  You won't necessarily have an AuditId with that value in the dbo.Audit table.

Comment: I want keep mapping between Audit and AuditField table.